# React-native check if my param is undefined

Tags: react-native, parameters, undefined

I'm looking for a way to check if my params is undefined.
I tried it but it doesn't work :

```
componentWillMount() {
    if (typeof this.props.navigation.state.params.Username != 'undefined'){
        this.getInfos()
    } else {
        this.navigate('ComponentOne');
    }
}
```

Still have this error : "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.state.params.Username')"

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try using componentDidMount() instead of componentWillMount()**

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (this.props.navigation.state.params.Username){
        this.getInfos()
    } else {
        this.navigate('ComponentOne');
    }
}
```

If still, you're getting this undefined error then your 'params' must itself be undefined. You cannot use dot operator on undefined

```
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params)
```

check if its undefined and debug where your making mistake

Comment: @DuvalTheophane It's same as my answer, so what is the result of console.log()?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (this.props.navigation.state.params.Username) {
    this.getInfos()
}
```

or replace single quote by double quote (Tested in Reactjs):

```
if (typeof this.props.navigation.state.params.Username != "undefined") {
     this.getInfos()
}
```

Comment: @DuvalTheophane do you try replace single quote by double quote for "undefined"?